# What is the purpose of serviceMethod in a Grails service?

Tags: grails

I'm wondering why an empty serviceMethod method is placed when you create a new service in Grails. Should I fill it out with code and call it? Or is it a hint that this class should have methods put in it? Is the name "serviceMethod" special to Grails?

Comment: just a hint that it should have methods

Comment: Your second guess is correct. Much like a controller is created with an `index()` method, the `serviceMethod()` is simply a hint.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a Grails command like `create-service`, Grails performs some code generation based on default templates. The template for a new service looks like this:

```
@artifact.package@class @artifact.name@ {

    static transactional = true

    def serviceMethod() {

    }
}
```

You can run `grails install-templates` and check out the files within `src/templates` to view or customize the code generated by Grails.

Answer (score 0):

This is just there as a placeholder/hint/example of where you place your own methods in a service. Typically you will end up deleting the provided implementation and putting your own.